# Help me learn how effective this new medication is:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't quite understand exactly how effective this med is because I don't know the proper equation. Here is what I know: A medication called Rebif has proven to be 67% better than a placebo. This NEW medication is 47% more effective than Rebif. So exactly how much better would it be against a placebo? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Placebo is $P$, Rebif is $R$, and the new medication is $N$.

$
R=1.67P \\
N=1.47R  \\
N=1.47(1.67P) \\
N=2.4549P \\
$

This new medication is almost $2 \frac{1}{2}$ times better than a placebo.

Comment: Is it possible to know the percentage?

Comment: @Kim multiply and divide by 100

Comment: @ritwiksinha is correct.  It's 245.49%.  However, I am slightly confused about the vague notion of one type of medication being "better" than another.

Comment: I'm confused entirely by that percentage. If something is 100% better than placebo, that means it's a cure. How can it be 245% better than placebo?

Comment: Here is the article. http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/05/08/the-revolutionary-multiple-sclerosis-drug-youve-ne.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can illustrate the answer by giving some meaning to the percentages:

Let's say placebo "cured" 100 people and all other medicines we will work in terms of this:

- Rebif  was $67$% better, so it "cured" $167$ people
- New medication was $47$% better than Rebif, so it cured $245.49$ people (Let's keep the decimals in)
- Now we look at the ratio of Rebif to Placebo: Which is $\frac{245.49}{100} = 2.4549$ times better

---

To get a percentage, times by $100$, to get:

### **$245.49$% Better**

Comment: I much better understand this now. Although, it is still hard for me to conceptualize percentages over 100%. These medications measure in terms of reduction in Multiple Sclerosis relapses. When a medication says they are 67% effective at reducing relapses, I understand that. 245% reduction in relapses is very confusing to me. For instance, if a medication was 100% effective in reducing relapses, it would be an MS cure...see what I mean?

Comment: Let's say that out of 1000 people, placebo "cured" 100... that's our baseline ($10$%)... Rebif cured 167 people ($16.7$%)... and the new medication cured 245 people  ($24.5$%)... we have not got a sample set, so it is strange to think about it having a 245% success rate... This can not be the case of course... You might be thinking that the placebo has  $100$% success rate, so anything above it can not be possible... However, placebo can not have a  $100$% success rate (and then we compare other medicines to that)

Comment: Making the sample set very large makes it slightly easier to understand

Comment: Wow. I understand now and this is very sobering and depressing. So this new med can't even cure half of the patients in the study?

Comment: @Kim No, it just depends on the sample space... In your original question, you wanted to know the ratio between placebo and the new med (2.45). Without a sample space, you cannot tell how many people were cured... I just made up 1000 people, to illustrate that it does not mean that the medicine was 245% successful

Comment: I think it's 74.8

Comment: @Kim What is 74.8?

Comment: 24.5% - 16.7% = 7.8          7.8 + 67 = 74.8%    It's 74.8% effective.

Comment: Why would you subtract them? @Kim

Comment: Remember that you are looking at ratios